# I need help understanding the use of brackets

Tags: c++

Why does code 1 work without parenthesis after the if-statement while code 2 doesn't work. The code is to look notify the duplication of the same string.

code 1:

```
int main()
{
  string previous = " ";
  string current;
  while(cin >> current){
    if(previous == current)
      cout << "repeated word: " << current << endl;
      previous = current;
  }
}
```

code 2:

```
int main()
{
  string previous = " ";
  string current;
  while(cin >> current){
    if(previous == current)
    {
      cout << "repeated word: " << current << endl;
      previous = current;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In code 1, only the first line is under the if.       previous = current; will execute anyway. In code 2, both lines are under the if.

Comment: In the first code only the `cout` is in the `if`. So after the `if` (but still in the `while`), `previous` takes the `current` value. In C++, blocks are defined by {} and not by indentation.

Comment: In C++, the indentation is fully ignored by the compiler. (That's why the syntax of C++ as well as C is called [Free-form language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-form_language).) Blocks are remarked by the curly braces only. (This is in opposition to e.g. Python where indentation is part of the syntax.)

Comment: If you have access to Coverity [disclaimer: Coverity is part of the company that I work for, though in a separate devision] then it can detect such indentation issues.

Comment: you are actually creating an infinite loop here you must use a loop control variable to avoid creating an infinite loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code :

```
if(previous == current)
  cout << "repeated word: " << current << endl;
  previous = current;
```

is equal to:

```
if(previous == current)
{
  cout << "repeated word: " << current << endl;
}
previous = current;
```

which is, obviously, **not** equal to:

```
if(previous == current)
{
  cout << "repeated word: " << current << endl;
  previous = current;
}
```

The tabs or spaces you put in front of `previous = current;` in the first code have nothing to do with the compiler. It is just style (which is misleading style in your case).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: You are welcome. please remember to tick the answer as accepted if it solved your problem and you found it useful